# Javascript - Replacing multiple strings in a text box

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a sort of "find and replace" system for my users to paste their current html and replace another website's urls with another's. Basically, i need files.enjin.com/(6 digit unique code) to be replaced with advena.io/. This is what I have already (i'm using a random's image as a temporary example):

```
<button id="replace">Replace</button>
<p>
  Original Text:
  <textarea id="input">http://files.enjin.com/435613/slider_images/slide1_1920x200.png</textarea>
</p>
<p>
  New Text:
  <textarea id="output"></textarea>
</p>

<script>
var mapping = {};

mapping['http://files.enjin.com/' + /(......)/i'] = 'https://advena.io/<?php echo $domain1 ?>/';

document.getElementById('replace').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {

  var newString = (function(map, oldString) {
    Object.keys(map).forEach(function(key) {
      oldString = oldString.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + key + '\\b', 'g'), map[key]);
    });
    return oldString;
  }(mapping, document.getElementById('input').value));

output.value = newString;

});

</script>
```

I know that the problem is with the expression that I'm trying to use in the first mapping. I don't know what else to use. I'm not so good with Javascript.

Thankyou in advance to anyone that can help.

**Edit:** I need this script to be able to change multiple occurrences of the specified mapping.

Comment: Would you let me know one or two examples of before and after strings...

Comment: Example 1 (before): http://files.enjin.com/435613/slider_images/slide1_1920x200.png

Example 1 (after): https://advena.io/slider_images/slide1_1920x200.png

Example 2 (before): http://files.enjin.com/759712/examplefile/example.html

Example 2 (after): https://advena.io/examplefile/example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. For anyone interested in the answer, here is my solution:

```
<button id="replace">Replace</button>
<input type="text" id="enjid" placeholder="ie. 435613">
<p>
  Original Text:
  <textarea id="input">http://files.enjin.com/435613/slider_images/slide1_1920x200.png</textarea>
</p>
<p>
  New Text:
  <textarea id="output"></textarea>
</p>

<script>

document.getElementById('replace').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {

var mapping = {};

   var id = document.getElementById("enjid").value;

   mapping['http://files.enjin.com/' + id + '/'] = 'https://advena.io/<?php echo $domain1 ?>/';
   mapping['PHP'] = 'Personal Home Page';
   mapping['JS'] = 'JavaScript';

  var newString = (function(map, oldString) {
    Object.keys(map).forEach(function(key) {
      oldString = oldString.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + key + '\\b', 'g'), map[key]);
    });
    return oldString;
  }(mapping, document.getElementById('input').value));

output.value = newString;

});

</script>
```

Comment: Would you explain a little about your regular expression -> new RegExp('\\b' + key + '\\b', 'g')